# Ubuntu 16.04 x64 Nvidia drivers 378.09 doesn't work well after suspend

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, suspend

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 x64 in an Asus GL502VM, it comes with a GTX 1060. And I installed multiple versions of the nvidia drivers trying to solve the problem but all has the same behavior. Currently It has the 378.09.

It works well, until the suspension. After the login it looks like this:

[Bug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEpkr.jpg)

The ubuntu UI blinks and has a strange visually behavior when I pass the mouse over it, it doesn't appears on the screenshot.

Change the tty doesn't solve the problem and sometimes it stucks at black screen.

If I restart or logout and login again, the problem dissapears until the next suspension.

Comment: downgrade to 375.26. its a common problem to many of us

Comment: We're having a similar issue as well, but in my case the desktop background is totally corrupt on resume; too bad 375.26 doesn't support my graphics card. (Quadro M1200)

Comment: I can't install the 375.26, it throws an error when I run the installer that I've downloaded from the nvidia website. I had to install the 367 via apt-get and it solved the problem.